# How to find if two slices are references to same memory?

Tags: go, slice

Consider this example:

```
sliceA := make([]byte, 10)
sliceB := make([]byte, 10)

// sliceA and sliceB are referencing different memory,
// witch eventually may contain same data

sliceC := sliceA[:]

// sclieC references same memory as sliceA
sliceD := sliceA[1:2]; sliceE := sliceA[4:5]
// assert that sliceD and sliceE share same block of memory
```

Is there any way to check that 2 slices are references (or not) to the same memory?

**EDIT**

The slices that I want to compare might not point to the same segment of underlying block of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two non nil instances, a and b, of type []T, share the same backing array iff

```
&a[cap(a)-1] == &b[cap(b)-1]
```

Note that it may be necessary to reslice a and or b before the test.

Comment: There's a problem : it tests only the array, not the slice position. See http://play.golang.org/p/g0AduyVU3d

Comment: but it may be fixed by adding a second test `cap(a)==cap(b)`. It should be ok then.

Comment: @dystroy Your program prints `true` which is a correct answer.  Where's the problem?

Comment: @jnml no, it's not, as I defined sliceD as `sliceA[2:]`. But it's OK if you also test they have the same capacity.

Comment: @dystroy It's a correct answer, all slices in your program do share one backing array.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, @dystroy probably I have formed my question wrong but I wanted to know if 2 slices point to same memory block underneath, they might not point to the same segment.

Comment: @canni you would have made your question less confusing by using the word array instead of slice. I answered the question you asked, not the one you wanted to ask...

Comment: @dystroy anyway +1 for you, as I have learned something new :)

Answer (score 6):

You can test the addresses by importing `"reflect"` :

```
same := reflect.ValueOf(sliceA).Pointer() == reflect.ValueOf(sliceC).Pointer()
```

[Example](http://play.golang.org/p/PUlLJhT2NZ) :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    sliceA := make([]byte, 10)
    sliceC := sliceA[1:]
    sliceD := sliceA[1:]
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(sliceC).Pointer() == reflect.ValueOf(sliceD).Pointer())
}
```

This tests the position of the slice's start, not just the underlying array.